# sudo apt-get update error on BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack, apt

I am using my Beaglebone Black rev C with the latest debian image installed. I have ssh'ed into it by connecting the ethernet ports and usb-ports of my laptop and my Beaglebone. My laptop has perfectly working wifi. After connecting into my Beaglebone and trying to update it, it gives me this error

```
Err:1 http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'repos.rcn-ee.com'  
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'  
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'  
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'   
Reading package lists... Done  
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'  
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'  
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'  
W: Failed to fetch http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'repos.rcn-ee.com'  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I also checked by pinging to deb.debian.org, but it gives me

```
ping: deb.debian.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I am using ubuntu gnome 16.03.04 LTS.Please give a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

While going through the same problem, I found the following website:

[How to Connect a Beaglebone Black to the Internet via USB](http://ofitselfso.com/BeagleNotes/HowToConnectBeagleboneBlackToTheInternetViaUSB.php)

Basically, you have to define a default gateway, define a default DNS, NTP Server to correct time, etc.

The biggest problem as also stated by the author is following commands cannot survive rebooting

```
/sbin/route add default gw 192.168.7.1
/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

The problem can be solved including these commands into .bashrc, and for that please look for the related topic in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216804/want-to-execute-sudo-command-on-shell-startup). Please note that, most of these options are very risky by default since it includes running sudo without a password.